# Maximum number of rational dimensions in a convex hexagon

Tags: geometry, parametrization

Is there a way to construct a convex hexagon (need not be regular) such that the number of rational "distances" in it is maximized. A distance is defined as the segment joining any two points in a hexagon. Hexagon has 15 such distances $({}_6 \mathrm{ C }_2)$.

Further, what is the maximum number of such distances which will be integers ?

For example, in a regular hexagon, there are 3 types of distances which can be made from one point to the others, as shown below.

[p, q and r are the distances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgZRt.png)

These distances are respectively 1,sqrt(3) and 2. Is it possible to make a hexagon where maximum such triplets will be rational ?

Comment: Use "distance," not "dimension."

Comment: It is possible to have a hexagon where all the distances between pairs of points are integers. The question has come up here before, maybe a search for *integral hexagon* will find it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3647840/how-to-construct-six-points-abcdef-on-a-plane-so-that-the-distance-between-any and my comments there. Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237291/points-placing-in-plane

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson